# What do the stars on my save mean in Little Inferno?

Tags: little-inferno

What do the stars on my save files mean in Little Inferno?

[image: 3 save files with different amounts of stars]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stars indicate how many catalogs you have unlocked on that save file.

Comment: Well, at least I was close